# Result from MSXML2.XMLHTTP to send it throw SMTP

Tags: vbscript, smtp

i have 2 scripts 1 retrieve my public ip and show it as MSGBOX
and the second it to send mail throw SMTP

i want the SMTP send me the result from the first script,anyway how to mirge both?

this to get my PUBLIC IP  ( Working Fine )

```
Dim o
Set o = CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
o.open "GET", "http://api.externalip.net/ip", False
o.send
If err.number = 0 then    
    MsgBox o.responseText
Else
    MsgBox "error " & err.number & ": " & err.description
End If
```

and this to send Mail throw SMTP

```
Set objMessage = CreateObject("CDO.Message") 
objMessage.Subject = "Home PC IP" 
objMessage.From = "***********@gmail.com" 
objMessage.To = "***********@gmail.com" 
objMessage.TextBody = "*I WANT TO ADD HERE THE o.responseText From the First Scrip*"



objMessage.Configuration.Fields.Item _
("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/sendusing") = 2 

objMessage.Configuration.Fields.Item _
("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpserver") = "smtp.gmail.com"


objMessage.Configuration.Fields.Item _
("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpserverport") = 465

objMessage.Configuration.Fields.Item _
("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpauthenticate") = 1

objMessage.Configuration.Fields.Item _
("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpusessl") = true

objMessage.Configuration.Fields.Item _
("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/sendusername") = "***********"

objMessage.Configuration.Fields.Item _
("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/sendpassword") = "************"


objMessage.Configuration.Fields.Update



objMessage.Send
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply assign the response text to the message body:

```
objMessage.TextBody = o.responseText
```

The date and time can be added to the subject like this:

```
objMessage.Subject = "Home PC IP (" & Now & ")"
```

Comment: can i add the date and time on the msg name on this script? like     Home PC IP  ( date - Time )  how to add it?